# Remember form values on form destroy and recreate

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have two react pages, each of which renders a form. When navigating from page A to page B, the form on page A gets destroyed, i believe.  Now navigate back to page A, the form values that have been entered previously in page A are all emptied.

I know i can populate the form with init values, which would require me to save the form content in the state / store.  However, given that redux forms already maintains a reducer for that form, is it currently possible to prevent it from deleting those values upon form destruction and recreation (switching pages back and forth)?

Thanks!

Comment: too broad? the accepted answer resolves it in 4 lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reduxForm({  
  form: 'my-form',  
  destroyOnUnmount: false,  
})(MyForm)
```

http://redux-form.com/6.3.1/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/

Comment: Oh thanks, did not see that